# Why the command substitution in the crontab job doesn't work?

Tags: bash, crontab, embedded

crontab -l:

```
* * * * * /Users/michel/Desktop/myScript.sh
```

myScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'Fact' -m "$(/Users/michel/Desktop/anotherScript.sh data.txt)" -n 'myApp'
```

it doesn't tell an error, but growlnotify's message is empty, so `"$(/Users/michel/Desktop/anotherScript.sh data.txt)"` didn't work.

but if I execute `/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'Fact' -m "$(/Users/michel/Desktop/anotherScript.sh data.txt)" -n 'myApp'` from bash manually it works a s planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell scripts invoked from `cron` are non-login, non-interactive shells, which means they're invoked in a kind of drastically stripped-down environment, and they don't source any of the typical shell startup scripts (`.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.).

I'm guessing that `anotherScript.sh` relies on something that's not available by default in this mode. Like something that's defined in the usual login- or interactive-shell startup files that didn't get sourced.

See `bash`'s (excellent) man page about the different ways `bash` can get invoked, and which startup files it looks for in each case.

Comment: The environment variables are different, PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH usually get you. You don't have a terminal either (I had stuff that broke on `stty` commands)

Comment: I found this suggestion helpful. :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239863/running-bash-inside-cronjob/240596#240596?newreg=cafa29d189c74c8a89df3f7e7da19f64